# Как узнать, работает ли CRON?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cron, crontab, dokku

Есть crontab файл для пользователя deploy с примерно таким содержимым:

```
15 2 * * * /usr/bin/dokku --rm run app-name bundle exec rails RAILS_ENV=production task:hello >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Дело в том, что я не могу понять, все ли нормально...

Пишу в консоли:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

И получаю это (сократил, там больше строк, но все они идентичны, за исключением времени):

```
Sep 24 06:35:01 news CRON[12437]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 06:45:01 news CRON[12650]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 06:47:01 news CRON[12695]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly ))
Sep 24 06:55:01 news CRON[12910]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:05:01 news CRON[13099]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:15:01 news CRON[13288]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:17:01 news CRON[13367]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 24 07:25:01 news CRON[13539]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:35:01 news CRON[13738]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:45:01 news CRON[13963]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 07:55:01 news CRON[14139]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 08:05:01 news CRON[14298]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 24 08:15:01 news CRON[14563]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Но тут, во-первых, от пользователя root, а во-вторых, пишет news, а я этого понять не могу (что еще за news?)...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выяснить - все ли нормально со строками в CRON?

Comment: Если воткнуть задание не стрингом в крон, а в скрипт, сделать его исполняемым и уже его воткнуть в крон - что-то поменяется?

Comment: Пусть ваша консольная команда пишет вывод , а в кроне сделайте не > /dev/null  , a  > /tmp/yourlogfile.log  например.

Answer (score 1):

news  - Это судя по всему имя сервера/машины под ОС Ubuntu.

Судя по строке из crontab задание должно выполнятся в 02:15 каждый день, исходя из этого посмотрите по логу что происходит в это время

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON | grep "02:15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно узнать работает ли в данный момент крон, то просто введите данную команду:

```
ps faux | grep cron
```

Вывод должен быть примерно следующим, если крон запущен:

```
root      1424  0.0  0.0  22000   884 ?        Ss   13:56   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
```

Answer (score 0):

RHL7, CENTOS7

```
$ systemctl status crond
```